# How do I send data via an Ajax Query to a Controller and then open a new JSP page as the Controller's return type?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

This is a simplified version of a problem I'm having. How do I send data to a Spring Boot Controller via an AJAX Query and then open a new JSP page? When I send data to the `url` in the AJAX Query to the matching URL in my controller class it seems to run the code within that method but not open the JSP (or return type).

For example if I were to send the following data from an Ajax Query

```
var hello = "Hello World!";

$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "/message1",
         data: { 
                 message: hello, 
               }, 
         datatype: 'json'
      });
}
```

To this method in my Controller class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/message1", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String MessageReceiver(@RequestParam("message")String message, 
                              BindingResult bindingResult,              
                              Model model) {

    System.out.println(message);

    return "NewPage";
}
```

`"Hello"` will print in the console but the JSP page `NewPage`will fail to open and will prompt no errors?

Usually if I just call the url in the controller (for example `/message1`) via a href link, or button etc the `NewPage` JSP page will open. It seems that the AJAX query is missing something. Do I have to update the URL in the Ajax Query to something similar to `/message1/NewPage` (tried this, didn't work), or add something to the controller because the `NewPage` JSP page will not open.

Comment: There are success and error callback functions in ajax, in the success you should check if your server returned "NewPAge" and if so, open the new JSP page client side.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, would you have any examples/documentation I could take a look at to try this out?

Comment: Ajax documentation: (https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/), also adding an answer below as an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the success callback function to your ajax like so:

```
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "/message1",
         data: { 
                 message: hello, 
               }, 
         datatype: 'json',
         success: function(data){
               if(data === "NewPage"){
                    //Open new page
               }
         }
      });
}
```

Comment: I added the following line below `//Open new page` and the page still won't open. ` window.open("http://localhost:8080/NewPage");`. Is this just me trying to open the page incorrectly?

Comment: @user9269133 Yes, do window.open("/ControllerName/ActionMethodName");

Comment: Hey Ryan thanks for the answer. I tried the following `window.open("/message1/NewPage");`. It didn't seem to work, so then I added an `error` callback as a debug where I checked if `data != "NewFile"` and still nothing happens.

Comment: Hmm. IS message1 your controller name? Also error: is only going to net you results if the ajax request errored, you should run this locally and set breakpoints through the development tools of Chrome or another browser you are familiar with in the success portion of your ajax request, and go from there. Here is a link which discusses opening a page in a new tab (https://forums.asp.net/t/1541992.aspx?How+to+open+a+new+window+from+a+controller)

Comment: Hey Ryan I got it working based on your answer thanks for the help. Much Appreciated!

Comment: @user9269133 Awesome. Glad I could help. What ended up solving your issue?

Comment: It was just an issue with the controller URLs